# Memory Utilization is becoming high on reading Excel in .NET using closed XML

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, closedxml

I have an excel file with 100,000 rows and 20 columns each. I am fetching the records using ClosedXml and then converting it into JSON using Json.Net library. However it seems that my memory consumption is increasing a lot. It shots up by about 2.5GB on running the code. Below is my code

```
public class Reader : IReader
{
    public JObject Convert(string excelFile, string sheetName, List<string> columns)
    {
        var workbook = new XLWorkbook(excelFile, XLEventTracking.Disabled);
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheet(sheetName);

        var headers = worksheet.FirstRowUsed();
        ValidateColumns(headers, columns);

        var itemRow = headers.RowBelow();
        var ds = new JObject();
        var rowCount = 1;
        while (!itemRow.Cell(1).IsEmpty())
        {
            rowCount++;
            var jRow = ConvertRowToArray(itemRow, columns);
            var key = CreateKey(itemRow);

            if (ds[key] != null)
                ((JArray)ds[key]).Add(jRow);
            else
                ds.Add(key, new JArray(jRow));

            itemRow = itemRow.RowBelow();
            jRow = null;
            key = null;
        }
        return ds;
    }
    private JObject ConvertRowToArray(IXLRow row, List<string> columns)
    {
        var jRow = new JObject();
        for (var iterator = 1; iterator <= columns.Count; iterator++)
        {
            var jVal = new JObject();
            jVal.Add("Value", row.Cell(iterator).Value.ToString());
            jVal.Add("Error", new JArray());
            jRow.Add(columns[iterator - 1], jVal);
            jVal = null;

        }
        return jRow;
    }

    private string CreateKey(IXLRow row)
    {
        return string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", row.Cell(2).Value.ToString(), row.Cell(5).Value.ToString(), row.Cell(6).Value.ToString());
    }
    private void ValidateColumns(IXLRow row, List<string> columns)
    {
        for (var index = 0; index < columns.Count; index++)
        {
            if (columns[index] != row.Cell(index + 1).Value.ToString())
                throw new FormatException("Column Mismatch");
        }
    }
}
```

The conversion is something like this: 
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
|   V1 |  V2  |  V3  |
should get transferred to:

```
    {
  "items": {
    "Value": [
      {
        "Col1": {
          "Value": "V1",
          "Error": [ ]
        },
        "Col2": {
          "Value": "V2",
          "Error": [ ]
        },
        "Col3": {
          "Value": "V3",
          "Error": [ ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

There is no issue in converting a small excel file, but I am facing high memory utilization issue on using a larger file. I am new to Json.Net so not sure of any tips or best practices for reducing the memory consumption. Any help will be appreciated.

**Update**
From VS2015 diagnostic tools it looks like the culprit is Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty and JArray.
[image: Memory utilization snapshot]

Comment: 1) Your desired JSON is invalid.  `items : []` is an array, but its contents look like they are object properties.  Upload to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and you will see the problem.  2) Why convert to `JObject` rather than stream?

Comment: Sorry about the JSON, it was typo error. I have fixed the desired JSON output

Comment: Use a JsonTextWriter to stream your JSON out to a file rather than building it up in memory.  See [Performance Tips](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm) in the documentation.

Comment: Your code will not produce the JSON you show.  I don't see any property names that correspond to the return of `CreateKey(IXLRow row)`.